# Mac OS Catalina: Detect when an USB device is connected

Tags: macos, command-line, usb

I need to know when a new USB device is connected along with the details of the connected USB.
I am planning to run a script continuously which will alert me when a specific device is connected.
I read online but couldn't find any such documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) meets your needs. From its web page:

- EventScripts allows you to assign AppleScripts, shell scripts and Automator workflows to be run when certain events occur.

Events watched include USB connections and volume mounts.

I have only recently discovered this app and have not explored very far yet, so I would be interested in your comments.

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) (which I have used for a few years) will do what you want, but is probably overkill (and over complex)  unless you want to get further into Mac automation.